# Clearing Memory (RAM) Cache on CentOS

Tags: linux, centos, memory, cache

I know this has been asked in a similar way in the past but I'm just curious.

If I made a script and made it run every midnight to check if my memory usage was higher than let's say, 80... would it be a bad idea to make the script automatically run `sync; echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`? I often get into an issue where my RAM usage gets to 99% because of this and I'm just getting a little bit worried.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why drop caches in Linux?](http://serverfault.com/questions/597115/why-drop-caches-in-linux)

Comment: How do you check the memory usage and free memory?

Comment: `$ free | grep Mem | awk '{print $3/$2 * 100.0}'`

Comment: Are you seriously asking how to get your computer to waste more memory rather than using it efficiently?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to do this. Linux will drop all caches if it needs the RAM for other purposes. See http://www.linuxatemyram.com/ and [Why is Linux reporting "free" memory strangely?](https://serverfault.com/questions/449296/why-is-linux-reporting-free-memory-strangely) for more information.